# How to show a UIWebView after app launch only after the page loads?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am attempting to load a UIWebView only after the page loads.  Until the page is ready, I only want the splash screen to display.  I tried following the first answer on this page ([XCode Prevent UIWebView flashing white screen after Launch Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376495/xcode-prevent-uiwebview-flashing-white-screen-after-launch-image)) but it doesn't seem to work...the splash screen loads and the UIWebView never loads.

Any advice?

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *loadingImageView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController;

@synthesize webview;
@synthesize loadingImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //**************** Set website URL for UIWebView
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://warm-chamber-7399.herokuapp.com/"] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:20.0]];


    //**************** Add Static loading image to prevent white "flash" ****************/
    UIImage *loadingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:loadingImage];
    loadingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"],
                                        nil];
    [self.view addSubview:loadingImageView];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    // Remove loading image from view
    [loadingImageView removeFromSuperview];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

 {
    UIWebView * webView;
    UIImageView * imageView;
 }

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    [imageview setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0)];
    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0)];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]]];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// UIWebView Delegate

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:webView]; 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the delegate of `webView`? Without setting that, your `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method will never fire.

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: on your viewDidLoad just before you call loadRequest:

Comment: it doesn't seem to work and I get a warning too (semantic issue).

Comment: In your ViewController.h, change `@interface ViewController : UIViewController{` to `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {`.

Comment: hm it's still not working. it's still stuck on the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you directly add launch image to your .plist file